# Learning C - why does my command line ask for input. I do not have a getchar()

Tags: c, file, printing

Hey I am learning C and trying to print the longest line from a file.
I am using code from the book ANSI C.
I do not understand why, when I run the code, command line seems to wait for input. I do not have a getchar() or other input functions so far as I can see.

Here is the code. There is a main function and two other functions

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define MAXLINE 1000        /*Maximum input line size*/

int getline(char line[], int maxline);
void copy(char to[], char from[]);

/*Print longest input line*/

    main()
    {
        FILE *fpointer;
        int len;                /*current line length*/
        int max;                /*maximum lenght seen so far*/
        char line[MAXLINE];     /*current input line*/
        char longest[MAXLINE];  /*longest line saved here*/
        
        
        if ((fpointer=fopen("arrays.c", "r")) == NULL) {
            printf("Error opening file");
            return 1;
        }
        fgets(line, MAXLINE, fpointer);
        max = 0;
        while ((len = getline(line, MAXLINE)) > 0) {
            if (len > max) {
                max = len;
                copy(longest, line);
            }
            fgets(line, MAXLINE, fpointer);
        }
        if (max > 0)            /*There was a line*/
            printf("%s", longest);
        return 0;
    }

/*getline: read a line into s, return length*/

    int getline(char s[], int lim) 
    {
        int c, i;
    
        for (i=0; i<lim-1 && c != '\n'; ++i) {
            s[i] = c;
        }
        if (c == '\n') {
            s[i] = c;
            ++i;
        }
        s[i] = '\0';
        return i;
    }

/*copy: copy 'from' into 'to'; assume to is big enough*/

    void copy(char to[], char from[])
    {
        int i;
    
        i = 0;
        while ((to[i] = from[i]) != '\0')
            ++i;
    }
```

Comment: ***How*** do you run your program? How do you build it? What environment are you using to create the program? What operating system?

Comment: Probably not the source of your problem but wrong nevertheless: `c != '\n'` and `s[i] = c` are undefined behaviour because `c` is never set.

Comment: For your actual problem - do basic debugging. Use a debugger and it can tell you instantly where the program is "stuck" at. Even sprinkling the code with debug print statements can do the job. That is, there is a lot more you can do to find or at least narrow down the problem yourself.

Comment: It's never finishing the loop.  I expect you meant to check if `fgets(line, MAXLINE, fpointer)` returned EOF (inside your loop), and leave the loop?  Or otherwise ensure that `getline(line, MAXLINE)` returns `0` if there's nothing read in by `fgets`?  (Don't assume it's `\0` for EOF...)

Comment: In a console application, a blinking cursor does not necessarily mean it is waiting for input. Your program is not waiting for input. It is _very_ busy going round and round in circles. That's called an infinite loop.

Comment: Hint: What happens when you have read the last line from the file? How do you detect that? Perhaps you should take some time to read about [`fgets`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets), especially what it [***returns***](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets#Return_value).

Comment: Thanks for the advice I will look into debugging in c and more clarity on my questions :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you fail to check the return value of `fgets`. When something could be read it returns its buffer after copying input there, and on end of file it returns NULL **and leaves the buffer untouched**.

As a result, `getline` will never return 0 and you have an infinite loop.

But that is not all, `getline` is plain wrong. As written, it will return consistently 999 (`lim - 1`) if *by accident* the initial value of `c` in not `\n` and else 0.

Minimal fixes:

```
    ...
    if (NULL == fgets(line, MAXLINE, fpointer)) return 0;  // immediately stop if file is empty
    max = 0;
    while ((len = getline(line, MAXLINE)) > 0) {
        if (len > max) {
            max = len;
            copy(longest, line);
        }
        if (NULL == fgets(line, MAXLINE, fpointer)) break;  //exit loop on EOF
        ...
int getline(char s[], int lim)
{
    int c, i;

    for (i=0; i<lim-1 && (c = s[i]) != '\n'; ++i);
    ...
```